# Can I nest JSX Tags into one another using traditional JS syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const JSXParentTag = <div></div>;
const JSXChildTag = <p></p>;
```

Consider `parentTag` & `childTag` above. Is it possible to nest `childTag` in `parentTag` to look something like this:

```js
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

using traditional JS syntax? For instance, something like this:

`JSXParentTag.child = JSXChildTag;`

---

P.S. I know you can write `<div>{JSXChildTag}</div>`. I'm wondering if I can nest them using traditional JS syntax as I'm sorting through multiple arrays of JSX Tags & it'd make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can't. JSX is a syntax extension to JavaScript. Babel compiles JSX down to React.createElement() calls.
In your example `<div>` is compiled into `React.create('div')`. If you steel want to write in "traditional JS syntax" you can use `createElement` method.

```
React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement('p'));
```